# В чем разница аргумента и параметра?

Tags: c#, терминология

В чем разница между аргументом и параметром в языке программирование C#?

Comment: это синонимы - "Our functions don't have parameters, they have arguments. And we win all of them."

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Параметром* (формальным параметром) функции называется переменная в функции, которая будет содержать передаваемое снаружи входное значение.

*Аргументом* называют фактическую переменную или выражение, значение которого используется как входное значение при вызове функции.

Пример:

```
double Negate(double x)
{
    return -x;
}
```

Здесь `x` — параметр функции `Negate`.

```
double r = Negate(5.0);
```

Здесь `5.0` — аргумент вызова функции `Negate`.

Таким образом, набор параметров (то есть, «переданных снаружи» переменных) функции фиксирован, а вот аргументы (то есть, выражения, значения которых попадут в эти переменные) при каждом из вызовов могут быть свои.

[Пруфы.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29)

---

Впрочем, эти два термина очень часто используют в качестве синонимов. Если вы случайно употребите одно вместо другого (не на экзамене!), вас без проблем поймут.

---

Как подсказывает @StateItPrimitive, в C# при вызове функции можно указывать аргументы в порядке, не обязательно совпадающем с порядком параметров, если использовать [*именованные аргументы*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264739.aspx): предварить аргумент именем параметра. Это может быть полезно для длинных списков параметров, чтобы не держать в голове их порядок:

```
string ComposeName(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    return $"{lastName}, {firstName}";
}

string fullName = ComposeName(lastName: "Hejlsberg", firstName: "Anders");
```

Или просто для лучшей читаемости текста, если смысл параметра не очевиден, исходя лишь из его типа:

```
await client.DownloadFile().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

Comment: ++ я бы еще добавил ссылочку на [новшество из  Visual C# 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264739.aspx), позволяющее указывать как именованные, так и неименованные аргументы, тем самым намекая на некоторое различие между этими понятиями :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive: Спасибо, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @VladD, не рановато ли использовать в примерах интерполяцию строк?

Comment: @Alexis: Будем считать это рекламой новых фич языка :)

Comment: Следующее определение максимальное короткое и примеры не нужны для понимания: Параметры задаются при объявлении функции, а аргументы передаются при вызове.

Comment: @Hit-or-miss: Если вы хотите дать альтернативный ответ, для этого есть форма под вопросом.