# Оператор typeof и тип аргумента

Tags: javascript

- Искал в инете описание "**тип аргумента**", но так и не нашел понятную
  инфу.
- Если вам не тяжело, то не могли бы вы мне на примере показать, что
  такое **тип аргумента?**
- Cтолкнулся с данным термином при знакомстве с **typeof**.

---

```js
function fux(a,b){ 

let sum = a + b; // a и b это и есть типы аргументов?

alert(sum);

};

fux(2,3);
```

Comment: Тип аргумента --- это тип данных, к которому принадлежит аргумент, который передали в функцию.

Comment: А можно показать на примере пожалуйста, так я лучше запомню))

Comment: "тип аргумента" --- это не специальный термин. Просто композиция понятий "тип" (тип данных) и "аргумент" (значение, которое передали в функцию)

Comment: Если Вам не трудно, то пожалуйста не могли бы Вы показать на  примере)))

Comment: Функция: `f = x => x*5`. Вызываем функцию: `console.log(f(5))`. Мы передали функции аргумент 5. Тип 5-и --- число (`number`).

Comment: Нет. Код в функции бессмысленный. Значения переменных (параметров, аргументов) `a` и `b` должны быть переданы в функцию снаружи - вызывающим ее кодом.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста мой пример внизу. Я все правильно понял)?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что такое тип данных? 5 -- это значение. Тип "пяти" -- это `number`.

Comment: Ок, а где здесь тип аргумента я не могу понять?

Comment: Да, их всего 8, строка, число, логический и т.п.

Comment: a и b в `function fux(a,b){ ` -- это параметры. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510254/ . Внутри тела функции a и b принимают значения соответствующих аргументов. Тип будет зависеть от того, какое значение передали в функцию.

Comment: В моей случае это будет числовой тип?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип аргумента -- это не специальное понятие.
Тип аргумента -- это тип данных, к которому относится аргумент, который передали в функцию. Замечу: "относится". То, что у значения есть тип, не значит, что этот тип явно указан.

Функция на языке C может выглядеть так:

```c
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
.
```

В сигнатуре функции `int sum(int a, int b)` записано, что функция
принимает в качестве аргументов два целых числа и возвращает целое число.

На JavaScript:

```js
function sum(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Как видно, тут явно не указываются типы аргументов, с которыми работает функция. Но у каждого значения в любом случае есть какой-то тип (по крайней мере в JS).

Пример:

```
console.log(sum('abc', 'def')); // тип аргументов -- строка и строка
console.log(sum('abcd', 4)); // тип аргументов -- строка и число.
```

Comment: А бывает логический(булевой) тип аргументов?

Comment: Опять: `Тип аргумента -- это не специальное понятие. Тип аргумента -- это тип данных, к которому относится аргумент функции.`. Если аргумент будет `true` или `false`, то да. у него будет логическое значение.

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо, можно закрыть тему)))

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fux(a, b) {
  console.log("a:", "type =", typeof a, ", value =", a);
  console.log("b: ", "type =", typeof b, ", value =", b);
  let sum = a + b;
  console.log("sum: ", "type =", typeof sum, ", value =", sum);
  return sum;
};

fux(2, 3);
fux("Hello ", 3);
fux();
fux(true, false);
```

Comment: А можете комментарием в коде пометить, где здесь тип аргумента.

Comment: @Black_Viper Так понятно?

Comment: Получается А и Б это и есть типы агрументов?

Comment: @Black_Viper Нет, `a` и `b` - это аргументы. Их типы это `typeof a` и `typeof b`.

Comment: В этом случае это числовые типы аргументов?

Comment: @Black_Viper Только в том случае, если в функцию `fux` передано два числа.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` возвращает строку, содержащую названия типа данных, которому принадлежит его аргумент.

- У каждого примитивноuj типа кроме null есть свой название: `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `undefned`, `symbol`, `bigint`.
- Все функции и классы - `function`.
- Все остальные объекты и null - `object`.

```js
function showType(x) {
  console.log(format(x), typeof x)
}

/* ES5 */

showType(42)                    // number
showType(12.5)                  // number
showType(NaN)                   // number
showType(Infinity)              // number
showType(Number(-1))            // number
 
showType("")                    // string
showType("a")                   // string
showType("abc")                 // string
 
showType(true)                  // boolean
showType(undefined)             // undefined
 
showType(null)                  // object
showType({})                    // object
showType([])                    // object
showType(/./)                   // object
showType(new Date)              // object
showType(new Number(-1))        // object
 
showType(function(){})          // function

/* ES6+ */

try {
  eval('showType(`${1}`)')      // string
  eval('showType(()=>0)')       // function
  eval('showType(class{})')     // function
  eval('showType(Symbol())')    // symbol
  eval('showType(BigInt(0))')   // bigint
  eval('showType(1n)')          // bigint
} catch (e) {
}

function format(x) {
  switch (x == null || typeof x) {
    case true:
    case 'object':
      return x
    
    case 'string':
      return JSON.stringify(x)
      
    case 'bigint':
      return x + "n"
      
    default:
      return x.toString()
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: O_o а в чем здесь смысл try / eval ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, для ES5 из early error сделать runtime error. Попробуй в IE запустить, например. А каждая строка отдельно, чтобы ES6 отработало даже если не поддерживается BigInt (попробуй в Edge 18 этот вариант и вариант, где всё в одном eval). А try-catch один потому что я их всё равно по возрастанию стандарта расставил.